# Refreshing Ionic List When New Row is Inserted

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a new item to the Ion-List and for some reason it never refresh to update the list:

```
.controller("HomeController",function($scope,$ionicModal,$state){

    $scope.windows = [{id : 1,title:"hello"}];

    $scope.addNewWindow = function(window) {
      // assign a new id to the window
      $scope.windows.push(window);
      // close the modal
      $scope.closeAddNewWindowModal();
    }
```

I have debugged it and $scope.windows is updated and it does show multiple items But for some reason the ion-list is never updated.

Here is the Index.html code:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="HomeController">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">MI</h1>

        <div class="buttons">
          <button ng-click="openAddNewWindowModal()" class="button">Add New Window</button>
        </div>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-pane>

  </body>
```

list.html looks like this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ui-sref="window-details" ng-repeat="window in windows">
    {{window.title}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The list is injected through the ion-nav-view as shown below:

```
 <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">MI</h1>

        <div class="buttons">
          <button ng-click="modal.show()" class="button">Add New Window</button>
        </div>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-nav-view class="has-header"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-pane>
```

Comment: try using $scope.$apply(); after push..!

Comment: Thanks! But that did not do anything.

Comment: make codepen..! it will be more helpful for u..!! i have tried your given code  and its working..!

Comment: I can see that the new windows are being added to the $scope.windows array but they are never shown in the ion-list.

Comment: if add button is in header..!and ionicModal is to add new window..!then where is list.html in this..actually..!?

Comment: The list is added/injected through the ion-nav-view as shown in the updated code above.

Comment: Ionic is suggesting that it might be a bug in their framework.